# How can I access javascript methods from jQuery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this plain js:

```
var innerText  = document.getElementById("TaskId").options[0].text;
```

And I was wondering how to convert it to jQuery:

```
var innerS = $("#TaskId");
var innerText = innerS.options[0].text;
```

This throws an error:

```
innerS.options is undefined
```

**EDIT**

In accordance with some of the debate I threw a quick speed test together:

js:

```
var startDat = Date.now();
for (var c = 0; c < 100000; c++) {
    var com = $("#TaskId").get(0);
}
var endDat = Date.now();
alert("jQ.get(0) took " + (endDat - startDat) + "ms");


var startD = Date.now();
for (var co = 0; co < 100000; co++) {
    var com = $("#TaskId")[0];
}
var endD = Date.now();
alert("jQ[0] took " + (endD - startD) + "ms");

var startDa = Date.now();
for (var comp = 0; comp < 100000; comp++) {
    var compa = document.getElementById("TaskId");
}
var endDa = Date.now();
alert("js took " + (endDa - startDa) + "ms");
```

results:

```
jQ.get(0) took 1042ms
jQ[0] took 1057ms
js took 136ms
```

Comment: You should test it when the jQuery object has more than one elements, like with class selector.

Comment: @gdoron - `TaskId` is a `<select>` DOM element with over 1000 options under it.

Comment: Check this: `$('option')[0]`  vs `$('option').get(0)`

Comment: @gdoron - I tried that, and got very similar numbers. `.get(0)`: 1468, `[0]`: 1357, `js`: 142.

Comment: How did you select it with `js`? Did you gave the first option an `id`?

Comment: Check out this [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-array-vs-get-selections-vs-dom) for a perf test.  `getElementById` wins the selections, but if you do use `jQuery()` - `[0]` is much faster than `.get(0)`

Comment: @gnarf - In your jsPerf link, when you test `taskId.get(0);`, was `taskId` cached before the loop in the prototype `var taskId = jQuery( "#TaskId" );`? Does taskId's instantiation occur O(n) or O(1)?

Comment: @TravisJ - The `taskId` ones are just to test `[0]` vs `.get(0)` performance, time taken to `var taskId = jQuery( "#TaskId" )` is not factored into those results, look at the results for the `jQuery( "#taskId" )` vs `getElementById` for the results there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A jQuery object contains an array of DOM elements.  If you want direct access to the DOM elements, there are a number of ways to get that direct access.  For example, you can directly get the first DOM element with this:

```
var innerS = $("#TaskId").get(0);
```

Now `innerS` is the actual DOM element and not a jQuery object any more.

For fastest execution time, use:

```
var innerS = document.getElementById("TaskId");
```

jQuery can be fast to code with, but is not always the fastest for execution time as jQuery objects carry some overhead with them (constructing them, sorting DOM elements, etc...).

You can get the entire DOM array like this:

```
var optionElements = $("option").get();
```

Of course, one of the reasons for using jQuery objects is that they have a set of cross-browser methods that make it easy to just use their methods instead of the direct DOM methods in some cases.  In your particular case, you could get the innerText like this:

```
var text = $("#TaskId").text();
```

Comment: Thanks, I really like the explanation about the selector returning an array. I should have realized that but I overlooked it.

Comment: `.get(0)` works really well here, but it's definitely faster to use `[0]`.  The `.get()` is super useful for returning a raw array, or for getting negative indexs

Comment: @gnarf - Speed on client side is a huge deal for me, so thanks for pointing out the comparison between native javascript and the jQuery `.get` method.

Comment: Also, it appears he is trying to get the value of the first option inside `innerS` - so `innerS.find("option").first().text()`

Comment: `$("#TaskId")[0]` looks ugly though

Comment: If you want speed, use `document.getElementById("TaskId")`, not jQuery.  jQuery is often the fastest way to code something, but often NOT the fastest execution time.  jQuery objects themselves have a fair amount of overhead.

Comment: @Esailija - I respectfully disagree.  In jQuery's code base, we often use `something[0]` to get at the DOMElement.  Since you know that jQuery is an "array like" object, it has numeric indices from `0...length-1` - It's safe, and very hard to misinterpret

Comment: This was just for a verbose example (as far as the selection syntactical sugar goes). I tend to stick to native javascript, but sometimes I want to be able to navigate around with the jQuery power :)

Comment: @jfriend00 - I was just pointing out that `[0]` is a property lookup vs. `.get( 0 )` being a function call.  The former is always faster, and it's equally readable IMO

Comment: **+1** Please add a section about `.each` to make it perfect.

Comment: `[0]` > `.get(0)` by far.  `getElementById` > `jQuery()` by far.  Nothing new here people... http://jsperf.com/jquery-array-vs-get-selections-vs-dom :)

Answer (score 3):

A jQuery object is essentially just a wrapper around a DOM element so in order to access the DOM element itself you can use either .get(0) or [0]:

```
$('#TaskId').get(0).options[0].text;

// OR

$('#TaskId')[0].options[0].text;
```

Comment: " is essentially just a wrapper around a DOM element" -> " is essentially an array of DOM Elements with a jQuery prototype"

Comment: ...with emphasis on 'essentially' there as it might be worth noting a jQuery object isn't strictly an Array but array-like in that it has a length and numbered indices corresponding to its DOM elements.

Answer (score 2):

Two possible solutions:

```
var innerText = innerS[0].options[0].text; 
// Are you sure about .text? I never used it.
```

or

```
var innerText = $("#TaskId option:first").text();
```

Comment: Yes, text works here without the `()`. I am not sure if it works in all dom elements, but it works in IE, chrome, FF, opera for getting the text out of an option dom element in a select element.

Comment: Thanks, I made some research and found these [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLOptionElement) for the option element, which mentions the `.text` property. On a side note: My second version is the jQuery way to get the first option of a select with id `TaskId`. I don't like the first version, which only uses jQuery to get the select. You're better of using plain js instead of that, like @jfriend00 suggested.

Comment: @bfavaretto - Perf Tip: Avoid [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) and other jQuery selector extensions in your initial queries. In this case `#TaskId option:nth-child(0)` is parseable by CSS and much faster in newer browsers. http://jsperf.com/select-options-text covers the performance test.

Comment: @gnarf, Nice to know! But isn't that something that could be optimized in the selection engine? `:first` seems much more readable...